# What platform independent browser libraries can I statically link against?

Tags: c++, facebook, licensing, cross-platform, browser

I am looking for a library that I can point at facebook's add app/authorize page. It needs to be able to statically link against corporate C++ code. I.e. LGPL'd code is no good. Something similar to Qt's webkit library would be great (but without the LGPL license).

Comment: What exactly do you want to do here, other than incorporate some code into your system? Do you need a library to pull down web pages, to log in to facebook, to manipulate the graph API, or something else entirely?

Comment: He said it, to display the facebook app authorization page.

Comment: All I want is to display the authorize page/login and have them give my app permission. Thats it.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need static linking?

Answer (score 1):

(Edited) I was wrong about LGPL, sorry about that. You [can](http://www.mozilla.org/MPL/mpl-faq.html) (see #6) however use [xulrunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner) which provides the Gecko engine (which is the engine of Firefox). Mozilla products are tri-licensed with the end-user being able to choose GPL, LGPL or MPL.

Comment: Look at http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/439136.html with regard to statically linking LGPL libraries. (They are considered derivative works)

Comment: I changed my answer, thanks for the info.